# Hyperlinks to a bibliography are one line off

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, amsrefs

I have long despaired of resolving the following glitch: If I am using hyperref with amsrefs, then all `\cite` links to the bibliography point to the line right below where they are supposed to. Here is an example document with the bad behavior and some other links that don't have this problem. In particular, note the target on the second page, which is exactly the code used in [`amsrefs.sty`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsrefs) (lines 595--597) to (apparently) produce its targets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\begin{document}
 \section{First}
 \ref{s:second}, \hyperlink{text}{link}, \cite{testbib}
 \newpage

 \section{Second}
 \label{s:second}
 \csname hyper@anchorstart\endcsname{text}Text\csname hyper@anchorend \endcsname

 \section{References}
 \begin{biblist}
  \bib{testbib}{article}{author={Ryan Reich},title={Title}}
 \end{biblist}
 \newpage
\end{document}
```

What is the cause of this problem? It really bugs me. I have asked this on `comp.text.tex` but received no useful reply. Hopefully, it is appropriate for this site.

Comment: It is definitely appropriate here ;-) No idea what the problem might be, though, sorry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you go Ryan. This should fix it for you...

```
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\BibLabel}{%
  \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{cite.\CurrentBib}\relax\hyper@anchorend}%
  [\thebib]%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}...
```

Comment: Awesome.  Guess I should send another bug report to the AMS.

Comment: Please do report the bug: this way it will get fixed for everyone

Comment: @Joseph, done..

Comment: FYI, AMS replied reporting that "the bug has been fixed, and an updated version of amsrefs installed on the ams server; it should be mirrored to ctan shortly."