# No section numbers, but still have PDF bookmarks with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

I have a document that has many sections. I don't want section numbers to show up in the document, but I do want the sections to show up automagically as bookmarks in the PDF using the `hyperref` package.

I know I can use the `\section*` command to eliminate section numbers in the document, but this also removes the bookmark. Is there some sort of compromise?

Comment: I know it sounds trivial, but it is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages, so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: With a KOMA class like `scrartcl` one would use `\addsec{title}` instead of `\section*` in this case.

Comment: Related: [Creating a PDF bookmark that goes straight to a section heading, not above or below it.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8427/creating-a-pdf-bookmark-that-goes-straight-to-a-section-heading-not-above-or-be)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can just suppress the appearance of the section number:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A}
a
\newpage
\section{B}
b
\end{document}
```

The macro `\@seccntformat` is responsible for printing the section number; by redefining it to "do nothing" the number is not printed, but **hyperref** is able to create the bookmark correctly.

The **bookmark** package is a good add-on, as it avoids some weaknesses of the original implementation of bookmark creation.

Comment: Would also be possible to redefine `\@seccntformat` locally to intermix numbered and unnumbered sections? This way the bookmarks are handled correctly in both. The only drawback, or required fix, is an addition to the table of contents using this method.

Comment: In case numbered and unnumbered sections are requested, the only way is to go with manual `\bookmark`, maybe redefining `\section*`. For the table of contents in case of all unnumbered sections, it's sufficient to redefine also `\numberline` to do nothing. Actually, it seems that Thorsten's solution is better. :)

Comment: Ah, `\numberline` yes.

Comment: Thank you, @egreg . Your solution worked but now I realize that I want the sections to be numbered, but not the subsections. Your solution removes all the sectioning commands numbers. I suppose my initial question wasn't entirely clear.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 27):

[`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) provides bookmarking functionality by means of

```
\pdfbookmark[<level>]{<text>}{<name>}
```

or

```
\currentpdfbookmark{<text>}{<name>}
```

in addition to others (see the [`hyperref` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf)). Here is a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\begin{document}
\section*{First section} \pdfbookmark{First section}{sec:first} \lipsum[1]
\section*{Second section} \pdfbookmark{Second section}{sec:second} \lipsum[2]
\section*{Third section} \pdfbookmark{Third section}{sec:third} \lipsum[3]
\section*{Last section} \pdfbookmark{Last section}{sec:fourth} \lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

It would be possible to make this form part of the section command `\section`.

If you're only after bookmarks, and not so much concerned with internal document hyper references, use the [`bookmark` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) instead.

Answer (score 20):

It is also possible to turn off heading numbering completely. Since you didn't explicitly say that you only want unnumbered sections, this might be an alternative.

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

This way you can use the known `\section` command. Again, note that this would turn off numbering of all heading levels.

---

[image]

Comment: `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}` will number sections but not subsections, which is exactly what @Jeremy wanted, right?

Comment: @Clara: According to his last comment, it is.

Answer (score 6):

I've provided a way to make LaTeX essentially treat unnumbered sections in the same way as numbered sections (but pretend that they are really deep so that LaTeX won't number them), hopefully without breaking other things. This is same approach used in classes like `amsart`.

This means that one can have numbered and unnumbered sections in the same document, and all will appear in the table of contents and bookmarks as usual (the latter if `hyperref` is loaded, optional), with hyperlinks pointing to the right places, without any effort except loading the package! See the comments in the code below for more details. Note that this doesn't really need to be in a package, I just thought it might be more convenient.

However, note that the table of contents gets an entry in the table of contents, which may not be desirable! My example below illustrates how to suppress that also.

```
% save this as fix-unnumbered-sections.sty
\ProvidesPackage{fix-unnumbered-sections}

% This package is available at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33696/
% It patches the standard classes so that they treat unnumbered and numbered sections equally! (At least, I've tested it with the article class.)
% As a result, even the unnumbered sections gets entries in the TOC and, when hyperref is loaded, they also get bookmarks as per the default hyperref setting for bookmarks.
% Unnumbered sections can also have short titles for TOC and bookmark purposes, just like numbered sections.
%
% It works by pretending the unnumbered sections are deeper than \c@secnumdepth (in fact, just by assuming that they are 1000 (\@m) levels deep).
% I believe there are no side effects to this...

% We just pretend that \@ssect, which LaTeX uses to treat unnumbered [sub*]sections differently to (maybe) numbered ones (if they are no deeper than \c@secnumdepth levels), doesn't exist.
% Instead, we always use \@sect, which LaTeX uses for numbered sections, and sections which would otherwise be numbered if they weren't deeper than \c@secnumdepth levels.


\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\@startsection}{\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}{\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{\@m}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}{}{\PackageError{fix-unnumbered-sections}{Unable to patch \string\@startsection; are you using a non-standard document class?}\@ehd}
```

Here is a test file to explore the behaviour (needs two runs):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fix-unnumbered-sections}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\bgroup\makeatletter\let\addtocontents\@gobbletwo
\tableofcontents\egroup


\section[First section]{This section is numbered}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection*[Unnumbered subsection]{This subsection is not numbered}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection[Numbered subsection]{But this one is}
\lipsum[3]
\newpage
\section*{This section is not numbered}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection*{And neither are its descendents}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output from the sample code illustrating bookmarks and table of contents]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very short solution that does not require any changes to the preamble, provided you are loading `hyperref`:

```
\section*{Acknowledgements}% The * makes this section unnumbered. 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgements}% This command makes the unnumbered section also appear in the pdf bookmarks.
```

Note: you do not need to call a table of contents in the beginning of the file for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

By using the [bookmarks package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bookmark), it is possible as follows:

```
\section*{Acknowledgements}
\hypertarget{Acknowledgements}{}
\bookmark[dest=Acknowledgements]{Acknowledgements}
```

Credits go to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11965/9075 for `hypertarget`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't upvote but I want to point to the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33696/no-section-numbers-but-still-have-pdf-bookmarks-with-hyperref#comment178432_33696) from @cgnieder (Thank you! You helped a lot. I even signed up for this)

For everyone with **`scrartcl`**: you have to use `\addsec{title}` instead of `\section*{title}`

It will solve all your bookmark and appearance problems (toc, hyperref, markboth, ...)