# How to use \section*{something} without removing it from the Table of Contents?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, starred-version

I am trying to insert an abstract and acknowledgement page into my report. I want to suppress the (numbers in front of):

1. Abstract
2. Acknowledgment

part by using `\section*`. But by doing so, it is removed from the ToC as well. Is there a way to maintain an entry in the ToC, while at the same time preventing this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: See also my answer to [No section numbers, but still have PDF bookmarks with hyperref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75528). There, the use of `hyperref` is optional and omitting it results in all unnumbered sections still appearing in the ToC.

Answer (score 9):

Use

```
\section*{Section heading}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section heading}
```

If you're using the `report` document class, then you should use

```
\chapter*{Chapter heading}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter heading}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are using your own section name it may lose count.

This is one option:

```
\section*{Your section name}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Your section name}\stepcounter{section}
```

Just add a counter afterwards.