# Redefine `\section*` so it behaves *exactly* as `\section` except leaves out the number

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, starred-version

There's any number of variations on the question "How do I get my unnumbered sections into the table of contents?" ...

- [Creating unnumbered chapters/sections (plus adding them to the ToC and/or header)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35433/creating-unnumbered-chapters-sections-plus-adding-them-to-the-toc-and-or-header)
- [\tableofcontents does not list the unnumbered chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129687/tableofcontents-does-not-list-the-unnumbered-chapter)
- [How to use \section*{something} without removing it from the Table of Contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106480/how-to-use-sectionsomething-without-removing-it-from-the-table-of-contents)
- ...

and none of the answers are any good to me, because they all involve sticking `\addcontentsline`, plus maybe other stuff (`\mark`, `\phantomsection`, ...?), at just the right place in the document.  In my case, the `\section*` commands are being issued by packages, and they don't give me hooks to insert stuff at just the right place; and also it is unclear exactly what set of "other stuff" I need.  It would be simpler and more robust if I could just redefine `\section*` so that it behaves exactly as its non-starred version does, except that it does not print a section number.

How do I do *that*?

Note: KOMA-Script classes are not an option.  I am currently using plain `article` for drafts and I will eventually need to drop in a journal's class.

Note 2 (from comments on an attempted answer): adjusting `\secnumdepth` globally will not work for me, because (a) I still want normal section numbering from unstarred `\section` etc, and (b) the packages that are issuing `\section*` commands can't be persuaded to use plain `\section` instead.

Comment: is `titlesec` an option?

Comment: `titlesec/titletoc` have a `numberless` key, which allows for different formatting for numbered and unnumbered sections, chapters, &c.

Comment: @touhami Unless I'm missing something, `titlesec` has no option which makes `\section*` do what I need it to do.  It has commands which are intended to *replace* `\section*`, but they do not help me, because I don't control the code that's issuing `\section*` commands.

Comment: @Bernard see reply to touhami

Comment: @zwol you are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can redefine `\section` to capture and condition on when the starred-version is used. Upon finding `\section*`, issue it just like you would `\section`, but [remove the number-printing mechanism through an appropriate setting of the counter `secnumdepth`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11669/5764).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\let\oldsection\section
\makeatletter
\newcounter{@secnumdepth}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\setcounter{@secnumdepth}{\value{secnumdepth}}% Store secnumdepth
     \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}% Print only up to \chapter numbers
     \oldsection{#3}% \section*
     \setcounter{secnumdepth}{\value{@secnumdepth}}}% Restore secnumdepth
    {\IfValueTF{#2}% \section
       {\oldsection[#2]{#3}}% \section[.]{..}
       {\oldsection{#3}}}% \section{..}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{TestA}

\section*{TestB}

\end{document}
```

[`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) provides an easy interface for (re)defining commands that may have a `s`tarred version, as well as an `o`ptional argument.

Comment: I'll have to experiment with this but it looks promising, thank you.