# Header after \listoftables incorrect

Tags: header-footer, front-matter

I am encountering a very strange error. I have sections from `\frontmatter` while others from lists of tables, figures etc... however after `\listoftables` the headers do not change according to the section any more but all show `List of Tables`. Can anyone help?

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[oneside]{um} 
\usepackage{blindtext}    
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter 
        \maketitle
        \input{frontmatter/originality}    
        \input{frontmatter/dedication}        % include a dedication.tex file
        \input{frontmatter/acknowledgements}   % include an acknowledgements.tex file
        \input{frontmatter/abstract}\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
        \tableofcontents*\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
        \listoffigures*\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
        \listoftables*\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
        \input{frontmatter/abbreviations}\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
```

This is the abbreviations frontmatter:

```
\chapter*{List of Abbreviations}

\begin{acronym}\itemsep-20pt\parsep-20pt %% if you remove these spacing params this list becomes huge!
    \acro{NER}{Named Entity Recognition}
    \acro{NLP}{Natural Language Processing}
    \acro{CRF}{Conditional Random Fields}
    \acro{LOD}{Linked Open Data}
    \acro{SVM}{Support Vector Machine}
    \acro{POS}{Part-Of-Speech}
    \acro{CBMA}{Chartae Burgundiae Medii Aevi}
    \acro{CLTK}{Classical Language Toolkit}
    \acro{TF-IDF}{Term Frequency-Inverse Document Frequency}
    \acro{KEA}{Keyphrase Extraction Algorithm}
    \acro{RE}{Relationship Extraction}
    %\acrodefplural{BUT}{Blocks Under Test}%    
    \acro{HMM}{Hidden Markov Model}
    \acro{URI}{Uniform Resource Identifier}
    \acro{RDF}{Resource Description Framework}
    \acro{HTTP}{Hyper Text Transfer Protocol}
    \acro{RDFS}{Resource Description Framework Schema}
    \acro{LOCAH}{Linked Open Copac and Archives Hub}
    \acro{EAD}{Encoded Archival Description}
    \acro{URL}{Uniform Resource Locator}
    \acro{TEI}{Text Encoding Initiative}
    \acro{KG} {Knowledge Graphs}
    \acro{CE} {Common Era}
    \acro{OCR} {Optical Character Recognition}
    \acro{KNN} {K-Nearest Neighbour}
    \acro{TEI} {Text Encoding Initiative}
    \acro{CNUE} {Council of the Notariats of the European Union}
    \acro{RAKE}{Rapid Automatic Keyword Extraction}
    \acro{MULTI-RAKE}{Multilingual Rapid Automatic Keyword Extraction}
    \acro{NO}{Notarial Ontology}
    \acro{NKG}{NotaryPedia Knowledge Graph}
\end{acronym}
```

Comment: As always on this site please provide a full (but minimal) example that (1) shows your problem and (2) can be tested as is by others. The sniplet you have posted cannot be used by others as there is no document class, no preamble, and it referes to files we do not have access to. Sorry, in this state of the question we cannot help.

Comment: I added more code maybe this will help

Comment: Your code is not self contained. Please make it into a single example no inputs. Also I'd guess these gives you problems `\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi` as you cannot execute macros with `@` in their name without special setup a setup I don't see in your posted code.

Comment: Usually this issue is caused because starred (unnumbered) sections and chapters do not appear in the headers by default (which is admittedly a strange default). The solution depends on how the headers are constructed by the documentclass and packages that are loaded. The `um` class is not standard (does it have anything to do with the University of Michigan?) so it's not clear how headers are handled. Do you have a link to the class?. You might try https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292408/ as a general solution (replace `section` with `chapter`).

Comment: this may help https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536752/how-to-get-header-to-reset-with-chapter/536763#536763