# How to get header to reset with chapter*

Tags: header-footer, books

Header should change from "List of figures" to "Preface."

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{extbook}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of figures}
\frontmatter
\listoffigures
\mainmatter

\chapter*{Preface}
\section*{Acknowledgements}
\lipsum[1-30]

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

I also get the same issue with other `book` classes.

Comment: I have a similar problem in my document. Once you write a chapter* _after_ having typeset the lof, the header in the new chapter* continues to be shown as list of figures.

Comment: see the comment by marijn on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536606/header-after-listoftables-incorrect

Comment: In this particular case (after inspecting `\ps@headings` in the example), I'd suggest to use `\chapter*{Preface}\markright{PREFACE}` or, equivalently, `\chapter*{Preface}\markright{\MakeUppercase{Preface}}`.

Comment: May I suggest that this is a bug?

Comment: @skvery -- It's not a bug, but a design decision.  Some publishers (among them the AMS) have made a different decision and update the headers whenever the chapter or section changes, including the starred versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple solution I found on https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_Page_Headers_and_Footers

> For ultimate flexibility, the `\chapter` command and its friends do not redefine `\rightmark` and `\leftmark` themselves. They call yet another command (`\chaptermark`, `\sectionmark`, or `\subsectionmark`) that is responsible for redefining `\rightmark` and `\leftmark`, ***except if they are starred*** -- *in such a case, `\markboth{Chapter/Section name}{}` must be used inside the sectioning command if header and footer lines are to be updated.*

about `\markboth` see http://texblog.net/help/latex/markboth.html

so to get what you want change your example as follow

```
    \chapter*{Preface}
    \markboth{}{Preface}
```

Comment: `\markboth` in this case should be entered as `\markboth{Preface}{Preface}`, otherwise the left-hand header will be blank.

Comment: @barbarabeeton on left I got the page number

Comment: I meant the header text.  It would nice to have that on a left-hand page if the chapter ends on that left-hand page.

Comment: @barbarabeeton This is a one-sided document. In this mode, `\ps@headings` doesn't use the `\leftmark` at all. That is why I [proposed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536752/how-to-get-header-to-reset-with-chapter#comment1356099_536752) to use `\markright`.

Comment: @frougon -- Ah, I spaced over `oneside`.  You are correct.  On the other hand, it should have been sufficient to specify `\markright`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Err... I don't understand your last sentence. Where did I say to use something else than `\markright`?

Comment: @frougon -- Oops.  You are correct again.  I was looking at the last bit of code in the answer to which this is a column.  Apologies.  (I'm trying to multiprocess, working on the next TUGboat issue.  Not doing that very well, it seems.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton No problem Barbara. Many thanks for your work on these gems! :-)