# How to get a table of contents with numbered and unnumbered chapters?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I'm learning LaTeX and writing an essay. I would like my essay to have the page "Sisällys" list every chapter as follows:

```
1 Johdanto                                         2
2 Päätäntö                                         2
Lähteet                                            2
Itsearviointi                                      2
```

Currently, it is missing those unnumbered chapters completely and unnumbered chapters should start on the same column as the number in the numbered chapters. How can I fix this issue?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \title{\textbf{Gummi 0.8.0}}
    \author{Alexander van der Meij}
    \date{}
    
    \addtolength{\topmargin}{-3cm}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{3cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[%
    left=3cm,%
    right=3cm,%
    top=2.5cm,%3
    bottom=2.5cm,%
    headheight=33pt,%
]{geometry}%
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\footheight}{17.99445pt}
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
title

$\,$

name
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\vspace{10em}

\end{center}

{\raggedleft number
Autumn 2022

subject

university

13.10.2022

}

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\onehalfspacing
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\noindent \section{Johdanto} lorem ipsum

\section{Päätäntö}
lorem ipsum
\section*{Lähteet}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[] lorem1
    \item[] lorem2
    
    \item[] lorem3
    
    \item[] lorem4
\end{itemize}

\section*{Itsearviointi}
dsadsd
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The `titletoc` package, which comes with `titlesec`, has a `\titlecontents` command, which takes into account numbered as well as unnumbered sections. See the `titlesec` documentation, §6 (A ten minute guide to titletoc).

Comment: There is also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292408/redefine-section-so-it-behaves-exactly-as-section-except-leaves-out-the which does something similar as one of the answers in the first link but more automated.

Comment: I tried to use the `titlesec` package but I was unable to find a working solution.