# Remove section numbers only from title

Tags: sectioning, numbering, sectsty

I would like to remove the section number from only the title, but display it in the figures and equations in the section.
My document class is `scrartcl` and I am using `sectsty`

I tried

```
\section*{Problem 1}
```

but then all my figures and equations become 0.1,0.2... instead of 1.1, 1.2..

How does one go about this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you have also normal sections or only problems?

Comment: Glad to be here, just started with TeX!

For this document only problems, But I might have to add Theorems later on.

Comment: I mean: are the sectioning commands you use entitled "Problem `<number>` only?

Comment: Yes, in this case.

Comment: To enrich my knowledge, what would be the simplest way to just remove section numbers from the heading only in an already formatted document without loosing the equation numbering?

Comment: Your last comment should be a fresh question, maybe with a link to this one. Please try showing a minimal example of what you have and what you need.

Comment: I found what I was looking for! [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33696/no-section-numbers-but-still-have-pdf-bookmarks-with-hyperref)
`\makeatletter`
`\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{}`
`\makeatother`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this more simply by defining a personal command. This is the simplest way:

```
\newcommand{\problem}{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \section*{Problem \thesection}}
```

Here's a skeleton document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\problem}{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \section*{Problem \thesection}}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\problem\label{easy}

Compute the following expression:
\begin{equation}\label{compute}
1+1
\end{equation}

\problem\label{difficult}

Using the result obtained from~\eqref{compute} in Problem~\ref{easy}, 
express
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2}\,dt
\end{equation}
in terms of elementary functions.

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are many possible refinements. For example, you seem to want to have sequences of problems. Here's an attempt at it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\problem}{ s }
 {%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\refstepcounter{subproblem}%
    \section*{Problem \thesubproblem}}%
   {\refstepcounter{section}%
    \section*{Problem \thesection}}%
 }


\newcounter{subproblem}[section]
\renewcommand{\thesubproblem}{\thesection\alph{subproblem}}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\problem\label{easy}

Compute the following expression:
\begin{equation}\label{compute-easy}
1+1
\end{equation}

\problem*\label{less-easy}
Compute the following expression:
\begin{equation}\label{compute-less-easy}
1-1
\end{equation}

\problem\label{difficult}

Using the result obtained in~\eqref{compute-easy} and 
Problem~\ref{less-easy}, express
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2}\,dt
\end{equation}
in terms of elementary functions.

\end{document}
```

A “main problem” is started with `\problem`, while a “subproblem” is started with `\problem*`. The equation number will still be the one established by the main problem.

Avoiding the explicit number in the command allows for easily change the order of the problem, by just shuffling around their texts.

[image]

Comment: In my current document structure, I have Problem 1, 1a, 1b, 1c.
How would I accomplish this?

Comment: @Ash How should an equation in “Problem 1a” be numbered?