# Remove paragraph numbers, but still have bookmarks with hyperref

Tags: hyperref

How can I remove the numbers of my paragraphs, but still keep the links within my LateX file using hyperref? 
It's a bit like this question, but then with paragraphs:
[No section numbers, but still have PDF bookmarks with hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33696/no-section-numbers-but-still-have-pdf-bookmarks-with-hyperref)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set counter `secnumdepth` accordingly.

If the paragraph titles do not appear in the table of contents (counter `tocdepth`), then the depth can set to a different value for the bookmarks.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{
  open,
  numbered,
  depth=5, % otherwise the setting of counter `tocdepth' would be used
}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\paragraph{Paragraph}
\subparagraph{Subparagraph}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But when I add a label to a paragraph and refer to it with \ref then it refers to the subsection. That's still not what I want. I want to refer it to the paragraph. Do you know how?

Comment: @JoeyTribiani - How do you plan to cross-reference an entity that you've chosen not to number? Not by its number, right?

Comment: @JoeyTribiani You can use `\nameref` or `\pageref`.