# Remove dedication from contents section in latex

Tags: table-of-contents

While producing dissertation, my dedication looks something like this:

```
\chapter*{} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}% 
\begin{dedication} 
Dedicated to my family and friends. 
\end{dedication}
```

I am also using `tocbibind` package for managing table of contents. For list of figures and list of tables, I do not need to use `\addcontentsline` to include them in table of contents as they are implicitly done.

I would like to remove the entries of Dedication, List of Figures and List of Tables from Contents section so that it should start from Introduction chapter. Though I would like these entries to be maintained in index (I am not sure what its called but its the one which appears as the side pane and from where we can navigate).

Comment: Related/duplicate: [No section numbers, but still have PDF bookmarks with `hyperref`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33696/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. If not, please clarify, using this as a starting point:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Dedication} \pdfbookmark{Dedication}{chap:dedication}
\chapter{One}
\chapter{Two}
\end{document}
```

Table of contents:

[image]

Working bookmark to Dedication:

[image]