# How can I manage the format of the PDF bookmarks generated by hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, chapters, bookmarks

I have a book with a number of empty numbered chapter headings, and am using `hyperref` to generate bookmarks in my PDF index. I would like those bookmarks to include the word Chapter as well as the number. Consider this example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, final, fontsize=12]{report}

\usepackage[bookmarks=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref} % appearance of links

% toc and index formatting
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]
        {}
        {\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad} % Numbered format
        {} % Numberless format
        {}
\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered}

\begin{document}

\vbox{\tableofcontents}

\chapter{}

\chapter{}

\end{document}
```

The PDF index I would like to generate would contain:

> Chapter 1            2
>
> Chapter 2            3

What the above code snippet produces is:

> 1                    2
>
> 2                    3

I am thinking of something like `titletoc` but really any solution would be great!

Comment: This may help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33696/no-section-numbers-but-still-have-pdf-bookmarks-with-hyperref

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to sneak something before the chapter number, you can update how `\Hy@writebookmark` processes its second argument. The second argument is that part written to the ToC, which in the case of `\chapter{}` would be `\numberline{<chapnum>}` only:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\makeatletter
\let\oldHy@writebookmark\Hy@writebookmark
\renewcommand{\Hy@writebookmark}[2]{%
  \oldHy@writebookmark{#1}{Chapter #2}%
}
\makeatother

\chapter{}

\chapter{}

\end{document}
```

Another method may be to distinguish between the fact that this change relates specifically to PDF settings. As such, we can change the `chapter` counter representation - given by `\thechapter` - to condition based on this via `\texorpdfstring`:

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\texorpdfstring{}{Chapter }\arabic{chapter}}
```

The above should be placed in lieu of the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` construction above.

The above solution should also function under

```
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
```

Comment: @Werner Would this also generate the "Chapter " prefix in the Adobe Acrobat section-links sidebar? Is there also a way to add a period immediately after the number, before the `chaptername` is inserted? And, since I don't have a TOC, where in the document should this command-cluster be placed? Somewhere in the Memoir chapter style, perhaps? (I would also like to do this with Part numbers and names.) Or should I start a new question and link it to this one?

Comment: @StonefeatherGrubbs: You seem to request a number of things. Perhaps a [follow-up question](http://goo.gl/vWjuk) is better. Remember to provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) so they can replicate the current behaviour, and be clear about the current and expected output.

Comment: @Warner Yes, the more I wrote, the more I was thinking that. However, I've just hit on another solution, which also fixes the problem of LaTeX formatting code inserting itself into the Acrobat titles: I will make separate titles for Acrobat, including "Part I," etc., with the `hyperref` macro `\texorpdfstring`. But thanks for the reply.

Comment: @StonefeatherGrubbs: Great! I added something to that effect in my answer.