# hyperref not generating bookmarks automatically in a template

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

I'm using the template from https://cn.sharelatex.com/project/5b81a8a5c5f2313c7802657f

and even after adding the code

```
\usepackage[pdfstartview=FitH, colorlinks, linkcolor=red, anchorcolor=red, 
citecolor=red,bookmarks=true, bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
```

the bookmarks are still not automatically generated.

Anyone can help?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}  %left margin position, reference is one inch
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}    %width of text=8.5-1in-1in for margin
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}    %reference is at 1.5in, -.5in gives a start of about 1in from top
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}     %length of text=11in-1in-1in (top and bot. marg.) 


\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}% Include colors for document elements
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[numbers,super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
%\usepackage[nolists, nomarkers, figuresfirst]{endfloat}
\usepackage[pdfstartview=FitH, colorlinks, linkcolor=red, anchorcolor=red, citecolor=red,bookmarks=true, bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\definecolor{background-color}{gray}{0.98}

\title{A fundamental revolution in quantum chemistry: final explanation for hitherto unexplained measurements of property X and predictions of property Y}
\author{Author A\thanks{Department of Biology, University 1, ...}, Author B\thanks{Department of Quantum Chemistry, University 2, ...}, Author C \thanks{Department of Physics, University 3, ...}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
%((Insert abstract here))
\end{abstract}


\clearpage



% makes references listed with 1., 2., etc.  
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
  \makeatother

\bibliographystyle{apsrev}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\normalsize


\clearpage

\section*{\sffamily \Large INTRODUCTION} % Not needed for rapid communications

%((Place Introduction here))

This section must answer the following three questions in detail (supported by appropriate citations):

\begin{enumerate}
\item Why is this study important?
\item What is the history of prior attempts (theoretical and experimental) to solve / study this problem?
\item How does this study advance the body of knowledge?
\end{enumerate}



\section*{\sffamily \Large METHODOLOGY}


You must clearly define the precise approach used in this study. If you are developing a new method, please make that explicit.



\section*{\sffamily \Large RESULTS}


\section*{\sffamily \Large First-order heading}



\subsection*{\sffamily \large Second-order heading}

\subsubsection*{\sffamily \normalsize Third-order heading}

{\sffamily \small Fourth-order heading}\\

\section*{\sffamily \Large DISCUSSION}


This section must offer a detailed analysis of the results obtained. This analysis must be logically consistent and scientifically defensible.

Unless your study is devoted purely towards development of new theoretical / numerical methods, you must either:

\begin{itemize}
\item cite existing experimental data that supports your conclusions, or;
\item clearly suggest possible experiments that can be carried out to test your findings.
\end{itemize}

\section*{\sffamily \Large CONCLUSIONS}

This section must revisit the three questions you answered in the Introduction and discuss the significance of the results described above. Please also clearly delineate any open problems / logical questions not answered by this study, with a reasonable (not wild) speculation about how those open problems might be tackled.

After your paper is read, the reader must have a precise idea of the significance, purpose, context and scientific validity of your study.

You must proofread your paper thoroughly to ensure that it meets or exceeds acceptable standards of international scientific communication in English.

%((Place Conclusions here.))

\subsection*{\sffamily \large ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}

%((Place Acknowledgments here))

This section must acknowledge all sources of funding / other support, any discussions with colleagues / students who are not co-authors, etc.

%((Additional Supporting Information may be found in the online version of this article.))

\clearpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% BIBLIOGRAPHY

%\bibliography{bibtexrefs}   % Produces the bibliography via BibTeX.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}


\bibitem{Coulson}
Coulson, C. A., Rev. Mod. Phys., \textbf{1960}, 32,170-177.
\bibitem{Malrieu}
Malrieu, J.-P., J. Mol. Struct., \textbf{1998}, 424, 1-2,83-91.
\bibitem{Shaik}
Shaik, S., New. J. Chem., \textbf{2007}, 31,2015-2028.
\bibitem{Hoffmann}
Hoffman, R., Schleyer, P. v. R., Schaefer III, H. F., \textbf{2008}, 47, 7164-7167.
\bibitem{Perdew}
Perdew, J. P., Ruzsinszky, A., Constantin, L., Sun, J., Csonka, G., J. Chem. Theory Comput., \textbf{2009}, 5, 902-908.
\bibitem{Koros}
Koros, W. J.; Chern, R. T. In Handbook of Separation Process Technology; Rousseau, E. D.; Russell, B., Eds.; Wiley: New York, \textbf{1987}; Vol. 2, Chapter 20, pp 34-45.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! The problem is that you use unnumbered sections, which normally don't appear in bookmarks. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33696/no-section-numbers-but-still-have-pdf-bookmarks-with-hyperref You could use this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33701/36296 but you would have to change all `\section*` to `\section`. If you don't want to do this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75528/36296 could help

Comment: @Ivan Good to hear!