# How to add bookmarks for un-numbered Sections?

Tags: bookmarks

I would like to bookmark sections even when they are not numbered.
When I set sections as

```
\section*{Section 1}
```

Latex compiles the document with no bookmarks and there no numbers on sections. So it is typed as "Section 1" on the document.

When I set it as:

```
\section{Section 1}
```

Bookmarks are generated, but then it is typed as "1 Section 1" on the document.

How do I set it so that there are no numbers in front of the sections but there are still bookmarks?

Comment: why don't you use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` to suppress numbering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @egreg  -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33701/197451

suppress the appearance of the section number -- The macro @seccntformat is responsible for printing the section number; by redefining it to "do nothing" the number is not printed, but hyperref is able to create the bookmark correctly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A}
a

\newpage
\section{B}
b
\end{document}
```