# hypertarget seems to aim a line too low

Tags: pdf, bookmarks, hypertarget

I made a small example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdfstartview=FitH]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
we want to go\hypertarget{t1}{} here.\\
instead we go here.
\bookmark[dest=t1]{goto 1}
\end{document}
```

When clicking the bookmark in the PDF file, the second line will be at the top of the screen, but the first one should. What do I understand wrongly? How do I have to do it?

**edit**: my summary of the answers (I feel that `\Hy@raisedlink` looks a bit better since the other one is really close to the top of the line). the problem is: this doesn't seem to work in macros. I always get an 'undefined control sequence' error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdfstartview=FitH]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\newcommand{\linkdest}{\makeatletter\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{t4}{}}\makeatother}
\begin{document}
apparently \textbackslash hypertarget marks the bottom of its line instead
of the top. it can be fixed using \textbackslash Hy@raisedlink or 
\textbackslash raisebox (a bit lower).\\\\
we cant go\hypertarget{t1}{} here.\\\\
we can go here\makeatletter\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{t2}{}}\makeatother{}. %
we can go here\raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\hypertarget{t3}{}} too.\\\\
go here by macro: \linkdest .
\bookmark[dest=t1]{cant} 
\bookmark[dest=t2]{can} 
\bookmark[dest=t3]{can too}
\bookmark[dest=t4]{macro}
\end{document}
```

**edit 2**: OK, it works now. I have noticed that `\Hy@raisedlink` seems to pretend that the link was in the line above (e.g. it can go to the end of a page if the marked place is at the beginning of the next) while `\raisebox` goes to the top of the current text-line (thereby sometimes cutting big formulas).

Comment: `\makeatletter` is somewhat tricky.  Basically, you should define your macro like `\makeatletter\newcommand{nop}{\Hy@raisedlink{...}}\makeatother`.  Think of the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair as an environment in which it is acceptable to use `@` in macros.

Comment: Interestingly, because of the way TeX parses its input, even if you have a macro (such as \nop) whose contents contain @'s in other macros, it is usable anywhere, as long as its own name has only letters.

Comment: This is easy. Just put `\hypertarget{}{}` one line above where you actually want `\hyperlink{}{}` to hit.

Comment: I have a similar question and answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411987/how-to-fix-hypertargets-directing-links-to-the-line-after-the-target-it-looks-l).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This was my very first question here: [Hyperlinks to a bibliography are one line off](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2068/hyperlinks-to-a-bibliography-are-one-line-off).  The reason is that `hyperref` links, like all TeX boxes, are placed on the baseline.  There is an internal command `\Hy@raisedlink` which does more or less what Bruno's answer describes.  Here is an example of its usage both inside and outside macros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
 \newcommand{\linkdest}[1]{\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{#1}{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

 Here are targets created
 \makeatletter
  \Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{t1}{}}directly
 \makeatother
 and \linkdest{t2}indirectly.  Here is one created by \hypertarget{t3}{}hypertarget.

 \hyperlink{t1}{Here} \hyperlink{t2}{are} \hyperlink{t3}{links}

\end{document}
```

The first two links should point above their targets, and the third one should point to its baseline.

Comment: I dont understand. Is `\Hy@raisedlink` supposed to replace `\hyperref` or `\bookmark`? It sounds like the latter but I didnt find any examples.

Comment: @peter: No, it's a modifier.  You use it like this: `\makeatletter \Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{target}{}} \makeatother`, and the link is raised like in Bruno's answer.  However, the second argument of `\hypertarget` should be empty (also like in Bruno's answer), or else the contents will also be raised.  Basically, don't use this command, but do what Bruno did.  However, some `hyperref` macros, such as `\phantomsection`, do call it internally, and produce correctly raised links.

Comment: thanks. it's in the `\hyperref` package, right? because when I use it I get undefined control sequence errors whereever my macro containing it appears. also `@raisedlink` appears in the output file.

Comment: @peter: Yes, you have to load `hyperref` (the `Hy@` prefix is its personal namespace).  Also, if you use it within a document, you have to wrap the whole expression in `\makeatletter...\makeatother` like I did, so that `@` will be considered part of the macro name.  If you are getting `@raisedlink` in the output, it sounds like this is the reason.

Comment: i put it in a minimal example, see edited question. it works if i insert it directly, but it doesnt if i put it inside a macro (which is unfortunately my intended use). i'd like it if you could have a look at that.

Comment: @RyanReich ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
\@let@token ...fvmode \else \aftergroup \maybe@ic 
                                                  \fi 
l.107 \makeatletter
                    \Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{68909206}{}}asdf

Comment: Thank you!  I only realised the problem once my book was already published. :/  It is nonsensical that `hyperref` links are placed on the baseline and one can find the solution only after a complicated search.

Answer (score 11):

I remember having the same problem (and failing to get a good solution). A clunky way is to raise the target by hand with `\raisebox` (from the graphicx package, I believe).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
If we try to go \hypertarget{t1}{here}, this fails 
(it bring us at the bottom of the word ``here''), 
as you can \hyperlink{t1}{check}.

If we use some dirty code to raise the 
target\raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\hypertarget{t2}{}},  %% 
then we will go to the right place. A \verb|\strut|
is a zero-width object whose height above the baseline
and depth below the baseline are such that it spans
the line completely from top to bottom. Then \verb|\ht\strutbox|
gives the height of such a \verb|\strut|, and our
\hyperlink{t2}{link} points to the right place.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had heard about such hacks, thanks for this concrete example. I am using it now and it works mostly. I still think I am missing something here (or is it really the purpose of `\hypertarget` to mark the bottom of it's target?), so I will still wait a bit until I accept this as answer (which will, I assume, discourage others from answering more).

Comment: @peter: I don't think that you should accept this answer, even after some time: there must definitely be a better answer, and I only posted this to solve your problem in the short term (I'd be happy myself to know a better way).

Comment: Unfortunately this breaks formatting in various ways, adding extra space and removing line breaks.

Comment: Probably need to add `\smash`, so `\smash{\raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{...}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to violate guidelines, but I don't yet have enough reputation to comment. The problem that `\Hy@raisedlink` may wind up at the end of the previous page seems significant to me.  The problem of `\raisebox` looking bad because it is too close to the top of the line can be solved by using a coefficient: `\raisebox{1.2\ht\strutbox}` looks pretty good to my eye.