# Back link all headings with respective TOC entry

Tags: packages, links

I came across a PDF which mutually links TOC entries and the headings present in the text body. It was created using Adobe Indesign. If I am reading the book and need to take a look at the TOC I can easily click the heading itself to see it in TOC. This will be a helpfull feature if content has many sub-headings. Are there any packages to achieve this functionality.  Please guide.

Comment: Do yiu really need it ? IMo  the bookmarks created by hyperref in conjonction with pdflatex do provide already similar fonctionality, don't they?

Comment: Yes I need it. It will be helpfull to see larger picture when many sub-topics are discussed. We need to create a label each time for each subheading and refer to it, becomes messy when many headings are involved. I dont know whether a package exists for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

First, using `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd`, one can add to the TOC filling a command for the creation of an hypertarget :

```
\patchcmd{\addcontentsline}{{#2}{#3}{\thepage }}%
   {{#2}{#3}{\protect\hypertarget{back\@currentHref}{}\thepage }}%
   {\typeout{*patch success}}{\typeout{*patch failure}}
```

Here I have chosen to alter directly the `\addcontentsline` command as it is still called by the LaTeX `\@startsection` (actually `\@sect`) after its modification by `hyperref`. This enable to affect all the titles in the TOC.

Second, one has to add the hyperlink on the sectioning titles. In both `article`  and `book` standard classes, this is achieved by redefinition of the `\Sectionformat` introduced in `\@sect` by  `hyperref`:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\Sectionformat}[2]%
    {\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth {#1}\else\hyperlink{back\@currentHref}{#1}\fi}}
```

Finally an MWE is:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\addcontentsline}{{#2}{#3}{\thepage }}%
   {{#2}{#3}{\protect\hypertarget{back\@currentHref}{}\thepage }}%
   {\typeout{*patch success}}{\typeout{*patch failure}}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\Sectionformat}[2]%
   {\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth {#1}\else\hyperlink{back\@currentHref}{#1}\fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Of course the ugly link appearance can be improved with the suitable `\hypersetup{...}`

Some caveats :

- This code is rather simple, but will likely conflict with any other classes or packages modifying titles and/or tableofcontents, namely the popular `titlesec` and `titletoc` packages, or `etoc` or `tocloft`, etc.
- Nevertheless, it can surely be adapted to other situations, by looking as the content of the sectioning macro by using `\meaning`
- In this spirit, the same procedure can be surely be used to modify the chapters in the `book` class, it will require to patch the `\@makechapterhead` macro.
- There is still a small default: the backlink opens the TOC page but the upper visible line is not the linked one, but the one just followingit.

**EDIT:**

Following the lines of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17057/hypertarget-seems-to-aim-a-line-too-low) I have slightly changed the `patchcmd` of my answer to fix the 'small default' so that the backlinks now point to the appropriate lines.
I also added the command to patch the `\@makechapterhead` as suggested in my initial answer.
I finaly added the `\hypersetup{...}` that I was talking about.

The MWE becomes now :

```
    \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\addcontentsline}{{#2}{#3}{\thepage }}%
       {{#2}{#3}{\protect\Hy@raisedlink{\protect\hypertarget{back\@currentHref}{}}{\thepage}} }%
       {\typeout{** patch \string\addcontentsline\space success}}%
       {\typeout{** patch \string\addcontentsline\space failure}}%  \AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\Sectionformat}[2]%
       {\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth {#1}\else\hyperlink{back\@currentHref}{#1}\fi}}
    \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\bfseries #1\par}{\bfseries\hyperlink{back\@currentHref}{#1}\par}%
       {\typeout{** patch \string\@makechapterhead\space success}}%
       {\typeout{** patch \string\@makechapterhead\space failure}}
    \makeatother

    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue}

    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \Blinddocument
    \end{document}
```

Of course, the `\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}` must only be used f the class has `\chapter`s.

I hope that this now a more accurate and efficient answer to yhe OP.

Comment: I have improved my answer to handle chapter and have better back links. Obviously, the limitation that this solution works out of the box only with standard classes remains unchanged.