# Cross-referencing forth and back

Tags: cross-referencing

I will try to describe my question as clear as possible. First a working example.

```
\documentclass[french,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{kpfonts}
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{ a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=20mm, top=20mm}
 \usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex} \setlength{\parindent}{0em} \clubpenalty = 10000 \widowpenalty = 10000

 \usepackage{graphicx,bm,url, amsfonts, latexsym, verbatim, xspace, setspace,mathrsfs,marvosym,wasysym,amsmath, amssymb}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
 \usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=red, urlcolor=blue, pdftitle={article}, pdfauthor={DSA}]{hyperref} 

\usepackage{authblk}

\begin{document}

\title{BlaBlaBla} \author[,1]{Dimitrios\thanks{\texttt{\url{dimitrios.@X.fr}}}} %

\date{}

\clearpage\maketitle \thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{itemize}
\item \blindtext 

See reference \ref{foo3}.
\item \blindtext

See reference \ref{foo1}.

\item \blindtext 

See reference \ref{foo2}. 
\end{itemize}

\newpage

\blindtext

\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{foo1} \textbf{The foo1 reference}
\item\label{foo2} \blindtext 

\textbf{The foo2 reference}

\item\label{foo3} \textbf{The foo3 reference}.
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

When I click to the link, I move to the associated reference. What I want to achieve is by clicking to an small triangle or a vertical-point-upwards arrow next to the reference to move backwards to the text that the link is. That is, like the forth-and-back effect that wikipedia articles have (see Figure below).

[image]

Comment: If you are looking for a bibliography solution and can use `biblatex` you could have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/396713/35864.

Comment: @moewe Thanks, but I don't want a bibliography solution. It was just for provide insight to I want to achieve that I include the image from wikipedia. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: This is a `bibliographies` - related question and not about the cross-referencing between documents or within section/equation numbers. The `backref` option of `hyperref` should do what you request

Comment: @ChristianHupfer See my comment above. (Thanks  for your feedback).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I rolled back your edit, because the OP confirmed that while the example screenshot was of a bibliography, the intended use case is not a backref for `\cite` but for the normal `\label`-`\ref` mechanism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an `etoolbox`-based implementation of a backref-able `\ref`.

Use `\backrefref{<label>}` to create a `\ref`erence to a `<label>` that can will be linked back to. Use `\backreflabel{<label>}` to set a label and output the backref marks. Note that `\backreflabel` should be called directly where the `<label>` anchor attaches. Otherwise you may end up with incorrect link targets.

The solution works by writing info to the `.aux` file, so it may will need at least two LaTeX runs.

```
\documentclass[french,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\backrefmarker}{$\uparrow$}
\newcommand*{\backrefmultformat}{\textsuperscript}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\br@currlabels}{}
\newcommand*{\br@linklabels}{}

\newcommand*{\backrefref}[1]{%
  \listgadd{\br@currlabels}{#1}%
  \ifltxcounter{br@curr@#1}
    {}
    {\newcounter{br@curr@#1}
     \csgdef{thebr@curr@#1}{\alph{br@curr@#1}}}%
  {\refstepcounter{br@curr@#1}%
   \label{br@#1@\the\value{br@curr@#1}}}%
  \ref{#1}}


\newcommand*{\backreflabel}[1]{%
  \label{#1}%
  \backreflabel@display{#1}}

\newcommand*{\backreflabel@display}[1]{%
  \ifltxcounter{br@link@#1}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{br@link@#1}}{1}
       {\hyperref[br@#1@1]{\backrefmarker}}
       {\ifnumgreater{\value{br@link@#1}}{1}
          {\backrefmarker
           \backrefmultformat{\backreflabel@display@loop{#1}}}
          {\textbf{??}}}}
    {\textbf{??}}}

\newcounter{br@label@loop}

\newcommand*{\backreflabel@display@loop}[1]{%
  \setcounter{br@label@loop}{0}%
  \whileboolexpr{test {\ifnumless{\value{br@label@loop}}{\value{br@link@#1}}}}
    {\stepcounter{br@label@loop}%
     \ref{br@#1@\the\value{br@label@loop}}}}


\newcommand*{\br@aux@readlabel}[2]{%
  \ifinlist{#1}{\br@linklabels}
    {}
    {\listgadd{\br@linklabels}{#1}}%
  \ifltxcounter{br@link@#1}
    {}
    {\newcounter{br@link@#1}}%
  \setcounter{br@link@#1}{#2}}

\newcommand*{\br@writelabel}[1]{%
  \ifltxcounter{br@link@#1}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{br@curr@#1}}{\value{br@link@#1}}
       {}
       {\@latex@warning@no@line{%
          Label(s) may have changed.
          Rerun to get cross-references right}}}
    {\@latex@warning@no@line{%
       Label(s) may have changed.
       Rerun to get cross-references right}}%
  \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\br@aux@readlabel{#1}{\the\value{br@curr@#1}}}}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \forlistloop{\br@writelabel}{\br@currlabels}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \blindtext

See reference \backrefref{foo3}.
\item \blindtext

See reference \backrefref{foo1}.

\item \blindtext

See reference \backrefref{foo2}.
\end{itemize}

\clearpage

\blindtext

\begin{enumerate}
\item\backreflabel{foo1} \textbf{The foo1 reference}
\item\backreflabel{foo2} \blindtext

\textbf{The foo2 reference}

\item\backreflabel{foo3} \textbf{The foo3 reference}.
\end{enumerate}

\clearpage

See reference \backrefref{foo1}.
See reference \backrefref{foo2}.

\clearpage

See reference \backrefref{foo2}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Wikipedia-like backrefs for <code>\ref</code>--<code>\label</code>]

Comment: Wow! Exactly what I wanted it! Thank you very much! Bravo!

Answer (score 0):

This is more an extended comment than a real answer.

I agree with previous comments for the easy way to do that with backref package or more precisely the `backref` option passed to `hyperref` at load time. But it could be interesting to extend it to  `\label` and not only to `\cite`. In my answer to question [Back link all headings with respective TOC entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460688) 
I have provided a solution that could be used as a starting point.

But this raises a problem of ambiguity : the reference to a label is unique, but the reverse direction is not, as you could reference a single label several times.

Furthermore, the future references are not known at creation of the label, and even if you decide to fix the ambiguity by choosing to back link to last (or first) reference, you will have to write it to `.aux` file and read it back at the next compilation, which becomes much more involved.

If you really need that, and left me a delay of a few days, I could extend the above quoted solution to labels.

By the way the requested feature is implemented out of the box  in several popular pdf viewers, as they can keep a trace of browsing history, thus lifting the ambiguity problem.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I understand from your words and the comments that this is not trivial (as I thought:-)!). Is there an easier way to achieve such a forth-and-back behavior? I saw with `backref` option. Is there an example somewhere ? And the upwards arrow in wiki manner?

Comment: What do you mean by "an easier way" ? Is the pdf viewer feature not sufficient ? For which subject are  you  looking for an  example ?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. If my understanding is correct the easiest way to achieve the requested feature with a common pdf viewer? `backref` option was a couple of times mentioned. Where can I found an example of its usage in the current context? Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Sorry but backref can not help "in the current context" as it works *only* for bibliography.  It produces beside each bibliogaphic item the list of section numbers (or pages if you use `pagebackref`) where the reference has been `\cite`d.