# How to add hyperlink to stemma written using forest package?

Tags: hyperref, forest

I would need help with the forest package. I have tried to add links to the abbreviations, but with no success. Could you help me?

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
    empty nodes/.style={
    for tree={calign=fixed edge angles}, 
    delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,
           anchor=north}{}
           },
                            }
            }

\begin{forest}
[$\Omega$, empty nodes
[G]
[[B][Z[H][AR]]]]]
\end{forest}
```

Comment: Your code is missing `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}` so cannot compile. The next issue is it is difficult to see what you are trying to achieve, could you make your code compile please and also add an example to your code that shows what you would like?

Answer (score 1):

To link to an arbitrary piece of text you can use a combination of `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget`. From the hyperref [manual](https://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.html#x1-220006):

> A simple internal link is created with `\hypertarget`, with two parameters of an anchor name, and anchor text. `\hyperlink` has two arguments, the name of a hypertext object defined somewhere by `\hypertarget`, and the text which be used as the link on the page.

If you want to link to a normal lbel, for example a section, then you can use `\hyperref[label name]{link text}`. Note that for some reason the label name is an optional argument with `[]`. The brackets have special meaning to `forest` so if you want to put this into a node then it needs to be surrounded by curly brackets.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
    empty nodes/.style={
    for tree={calign=fixed edge angles}, 
    delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,
           anchor=north}{}
           },
                            }
            }
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[{\hyperref[sec:omega]{$\Omega$}}, empty nodes
[\hyperlink{stm:G}{G}]
[[\hyperlink{stm:B}{B}][\hyperlink{stm:Z}{Z}[\hyperlink{stm:H}{H}][\hyperlink{stm:AR}{AR}]]]]
\end{forest}
\section{Abbreviations}
\hypertarget{stm:G}{G -- Goose}\\
\hypertarget{stm:B}{B -- Bear}\\
\hypertarget{stm:Z}{Z -- Zebra}\\
\hypertarget{stm:H}{H -- Horse}\\
\hypertarget{stm:AR}{AR -- Armadillo}
\section{Omega}
\label{sec:omega}
Omega is a big O.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that in most pdf viewers the position of `\hypertarget` is not entirely correct, it links to the bottom of the line which means the link jumps past the line itself (i.e., the bottom of the line becomes the top of the view, which means the line itself is not visible). There are some workarounds in [hypertarget seems to aim a line too low](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17057/hypertarget-seems-to-aim-a-line-too-low), but for this particular use case it might make sense to either put one link to the Abbreviations section somewhere (for example in the caption of the tree) or to have separate (sub)sections explaining each item.

Alternatively use a glossary. In that case the links are added automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{abG}{G}{Goose}
\newacronym{abB}{B}{Bear}
\newacronym{abZ}{Z}{Zebra}
\newacronym{abH}{H}{Horse}
\newacronym{abAR}{AR}{Armadillo}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
    empty nodes/.style={
    for tree={calign=fixed edge angles}, 
    delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,
           anchor=north}{}
           },
                            }
            }
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[$\Omega$, empty nodes
[\acrshort{abG}]
[[\acrshort{abB}][\acrshort{abZ}[\acrshort{abH}][\acrshort{abAR}]]]]
\end{forest}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Stemma abbreviations]
\end{document}
```

Note that this needs a run of the auxiliary program `makeglossaries yourfile` after the first compilation. Also note that this list is sorted.

[image]

Comment: This definitely should have non-zero votes, even if it isn't entirely clear (or, possibly, especially because it's not entirely clear) what the question is. ;) From a `forest` pov, it would probably be better to use the `linguistics` library rather than the `empty nodes` stuff, but, whatever the question is, it certainly isn't that.