# Changing the hyperref target for back references in biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, back-referencing

In my bibliography style, I have added a trigger to change the `biblatex` bibliography back reference mechanism to refer to the paragraph numbers in the margins ("runners") instead of pages.

```
\def\blx@addbackref@i#1{%
  \ifbacktracker
    \blx@leavevmode
    \if@filesw
      \protected@write\@mainaux{}{\string\abx@aux@backref
        {\the\c@instcount}{#1}{\the\c@refsection}%
        {\ifbool{bbx:runner}%
          {\therunner}%
          {\thepage}}%
      {\noexpand\the\c@page}}%
    \fi
  \fi%
 }
```

`\therunner` is added to a paragraph by using the macro from the `jurabook` class

```
\newcommand*{\rn}[2][]{%
  \if@dorunners%
    \stepcounter{runner}%
    #2\marginpar%
      [\hfill{\small\sffamily\therunner}\hspace*{\jb@runnersspace@length}]%
      {\hspace*{\jb@runnersspace@length}{\small\sffamily\therunner}\hfill}%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\therunner}%
   \else%
    #2
  \fi% do NOT delete the percentage sign
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\@empty}}%
    {}% nix
    %else
    {\label{#1}}%
}
```

Since the runner mechanism is the only feature from the jurabook class I needed, I have copied that macro into my preamble rather than using the entire class.

If I now set the `biblatex` option runner to true, thus switching `bbx:runner` to true, the back reference numbers shown in the bibliography show the paragraph numbers shown in the document margins rather than the page numbers for each cited entry.

However, if I click the number, the link takes me to the page corresponding to the number rather than the paragraph corresponding to the number. This means that I have an entry that is cited in paragraph number 10 on page 6, the number shown in the bibliography will be 10. Clicking that number, however, takes me to page number 10.

Does anyone know how I need to adjust the back referencing mechanism to make the paragraph the `hyperref` target of the numbers shown in the `biblatex` bibliography?

Comment: This is not the best place for asking this, but I see from your other questions that you are writing a BibLaTeX style for legal citations. Would it be possible to discuss this topic with you, privately perhaps? I have the same problem (in French, though) and would be very interested in knowing how you are dealing with it. — Sorry I can't help with your question, I have no knowledge of hyperref.

Comment: Maybe it is possible and simpler to use `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget` directly? I have used this combo in a similar situation - questions in the running text, and answers at the chapter end pointing to each other.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer My thesis currently contains around 600 cases cited, and since many are cited multiple times, probably over a 1000 case citations. Furthermore, my ambition is to have a feature complete legal citation style at some point. Shouldn't I be able to somehow set a `\hypertarget` each time `\blx@addbackref@i` is called and then patch the back reference mechanism in `biblatex` to refer to this target? My problem basically is that I don't know how `biblatex` sets the link? Does it use `\hyperlink`? How does it determine the argument for it? I understand the biblatex.sty code too little.

Comment: @jjbornheim It does use `\hyperlink`, and probably prefixes the argument with `page.`. The link is set by the `pageref` bibmacro in standard styles. You can see this by taking a look at `standard.bbx`. The `pageref` bibmacro is defined in `biblatex.def`.

Comment: Thanks @Audrey. Here is what I learned so far. The `pageref` macro prints the pageref link. The hyperlinking is done by the list formatting for this list. If the pageref list contains more than one item, `\DeclareListFormat{pageref}` calls, amongst others, three macros: `pageref:init`, `pageref:comp` and `pageref:dump`. If the pageref list contains exactly one item, it is printed by `\hyperlink{page.#1}{#1}` (provided hyperrefs are used). So in the easiest example (only one back reference), I would need to modify `\hyperlink{page.#1}{#1}` to refer to the `therunner` rather than `thepage`.

Comment: @jjbornheim No problem. It might help to see how `jurabook` sets runner links. I'm guessing something other than `page.` is used.

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, `jurabook` does not have a comprehensive back referencing mechanism that I could imitate. Rather, if a reference needs to be made to a paragraph, the optional argument of `\rn` needs to be specified and can then be referenced by `\ref`. So obviously part of the task is getting an automated way of creating suitable targets. I can do that by putting `\hypertarget{bbx@rn@\therunner}` into the definition of `\rn`, thus creating an individual target for each paragraph. I still struggle to have the pageref macros use this target rather than `page.#1`, though.

Comment: I made a small, yet decisive error in my comment three comments above. Instead of "The `pageref` macro prints the pageref link" it should read "The `pageref` macro prints the pageref list".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A whole lot goes on under the hood to collect and set the list of page numbers in back references. One easy way out of your problem is to make the page hyperlinks set by the `pageref` bibliography macro point to runners via `\hypertarget`.

The document below illustrates this approach. I've closely followed the code you provided, but you might prefer [other ways to set paragraph numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10513/4483). `\hypertarget` links to the baseline of its second argument, which is too low for runners. I've adapted [the solution in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2068/4483) to raise the link.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backref]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtoggle{bbx:runner}
\toggletrue{bbx:runner}

\iftoggle{bbx:runner}
  {\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
     backrefpage = {siehe Rn\adddot},
     backrefpages = {siehe Rn\adddot}}}
  {}

\newcounter{runner}
\renewcommand{\therunner}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:runner}{\arabic{runner}}{\thepage}}

\newlength{\runnersep}
\setlength{\runnersep}{0.5em}

\makeatletter

\patchcmd{\blx@addbackref@i}{\thepage}{\therunner}{}{}
\patchcmd{\blx@addbackref@i}{\c@page}{\c@runner}{}{}

\newcommand{\backreftarget}[1]{%
  \Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{page.#1}{}}\small#1}

\newcommand*{\rn}[2][]{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:runner}
    {\stepcounter{runner}#2%
     \marginpar%
       [\hfill{\backreftarget{\therunner}}\hspace*{\runnersep}]%
       {\hspace*{\runnersep}{\backreftarget{\therunner}}\hfill}}
    {\setcounter{runner}{\value{page}}#2}%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\therunner}%
  \ifblank{#1}{}{\phantomsection\label{#1}}}

\makeatother

\newcommand*{\rnref}[1]{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:runner}{Rn.~\ref{#1}}{S.~\ref{#1}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\rn{Filler} text \parencite{ctan,markey}. \lipsum[1] \vfill
\rn{Filler} text \parencite{companion}. See \rnref{run}. \lipsum[2]
\chapter{Titel}
\rn{Filler} text \parencite{companion,markey}. \lipsum[3]
\chapter{Titel}
\rn[run]{Filler} text \parencite{companion,markey}. \lipsum[4]
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here's the bibliography from the resulting document.

[image]

Commenting out `\toggletrue{bbx:runner}` back-references page numbers.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Audrey. I didn't notice I was logged out, so it took me a while to see your response. Your code does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to add a small detail to Audrey's solution. It bugged me that after I implemented the code, I would get warnings from `hyperref` like

> destination with the same identifier (name{page.19}) has been already used

I figured they were due to the fact that a destination by the same name is already set by the page numbering mechanism. So I changed

```
\newcommand{\backreftarget}[1]{%
  \Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{page.#1}{}}\small#1}
```

to

```
\newcommand{\backreftarget}[1]{%
  {\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{runner.#1}{}}}\small#1}
```

and added another `\iftoggle{bbx:runner}` test to change every instance of `\hyperlink{page.` to `\hyperlink{runner.` in the `pageref` format, `pageref:comp` and `pageref:dump` bibliography macros defined in `biblatex.def`. These edits can easily be made using [egreg's extension](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40705/4483) of `etoolbox` patch commands.

```
\makeatletter

\def\act@on@bibmacro#1#2{%
  \expandafter#1\csname abx@macro@\detokenize{#2}\endcsname}
\def\patchbibmacro{\act@on@bibmacro\patchcmd}

\def\act@on@listformat#1#2{%
  \expandafter#1\csname abx@lfd@*@\detokenize{#2}\endcsname}
\def\patchlistformat{\act@on@listformat\patchcmd}

\iftoggle{bbx:runner}
  {\patchlistformat{pageref}{page.}{runner.}{}{}%
   \patchbibmacro{pageref:comp}{page.}{runner.}{}{}%
   \patchbibmacro{pageref:comp}{page.}{runner.}{}{}%
   \blx@tempcnta\z@%
   \loop\ifnum\blx@tempcnta<10
     \patchbibmacro{pageref:dump}{page.}{runner.}{}{}%
     \advance\blx@tempcnta\@ne
   \repeat}
  {}

\makeatother
```

Comment: +1 In `\rn`, `\backreftarget` is issued only when `bbx:runner` is `true`. So you can just replace `page` with `runner` in the original definition. Those bibliography macro edits might be less of a pain using `\xpatchbibmacro` from egreg's [`xpatch` package](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch).

Comment: D'oh @Audrey, thanks for pointing that out. I modified my answer accordingly to make the definition of '\backreftarget` independent of `bbx:runner`'s value. Also thanks for suggesting `\xpatchbibmacro`. I might do that later to make the code more elegant, but as it stands, it does what needs to be done. I simply patched the macros using find and replace in my text editor.

Comment: I added patches for the `pageref` format and related bibliography macros. Hope you don't mind. Please feel free to edit or omit the new content as you see fit.