# How to fix hypertargets directing links to the line after the target? It looks like a bug

Tags: amsmath, bugs, hypertarget

If the hypertarget is in a text-mode location, links to it work normally (they show the target line at the top of the page). However, if the hypertarget is in math mode (of any kind: in-line or in display-math or in equation arrays), then it will direct to the line after the target.

MWE

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\hypertarget{test1}{target1 in text mode}

Filler text.

$3 + 4 = 7 \hypertarget{test2}{}$ More filler text.

Link 2 actually directs to this line, rather than the above line, where we would expect it to do the latter.

\begin{eqnarray}
x * y = z \hypertarget{test3}{} \\
a + b = c % Link 3 actually directs to this line, rather than the above line, where we would expect it to do the latter. \\
\end{eqnarray}

\hyperlink{test1}{Clicking on this link shows target1 at the top of the page, as expected.}

\hyperlink{test2}{Link 2.}

\hyperlink{test3}{Link 3.}

\end{document}
```

This seems like a bug to me, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Interestingly, it seems like someone has since approved my draft to the Wikibooks article.

Comment: Tagging one other who have answered questions for the hypertarget tag: @Mike. Unfortunately I can't tag more, e.g. AlexG.

Comment: Similar questions with answers

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17057/hypertarget-seems-to-aim-a-line-too-low

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2068/hyperlinks-to-a-bibliography-are-one-line-off

Comment: Hi, welcome. You can only tag other people who have commented on (or edited) your post, so Mike wouldn't have been notified of that comment.

Comment: I can't reproduce this any more, but it definitely was directing to the line before a few days ago.

Comment: This question is genuinely about TeX, why close it as off-topic? I think the similar questions are evidence that the problem is real. Also someone wants to answer the question and together that's sufficient reason to reopen.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, initially the question was off-topic as it didn't have a MWE and was about editing a Wikibooks article, but I have since edited it.

Comment: @JamesRay Great, thanks for clarifying. The question has been reopened now, so feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you can do:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
 \newcommand{\linkdest}[1]{\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{#1}{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\linkdest{test1}target1 in text mode.

Filler text.

$3 + 4 = 7 \linkdest{test2}{}$ More filler text.

Link 2 actually directs to this line, rather than the above line, where we would expect it to do the latter.

\begin{eqnarray}
x * y = z \linkdest{test3}{} \\
a + b = c % Link 3 actually directs to this line, rather than the above line, where we would expect it to do the latter. \\
\end{eqnarray}

\hyperlink{test1}{Clicking on this link shows target1 at the top of the page, as expected.}

\hyperlink{test2}{Link 2.}

\hyperlink{test3}{Link 3.}

\end{document}
```

[image: testing a macro to modify a hypertarget to display properly]