# Correcting the hyperlink anchors of (sub)equations with custom tags

Tags: hyperref, links, hyperlink, tags, hypertarget

In this example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412381:
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\linkdest}[1]{\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{#1}{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
        1 + 1 &= 2 \text{.} \linkdest{htar:target1}{\tag{T1}} \\
        2 + 2 &= 4 \text{.} \label{eq:equation1}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\noindent eq.~\hyperlink{htar:target1}{T1}.

\noindent eq.~\ref{eq:equation1}.

\end{document}
```

hyperlink **1a** points to the beginning of the equation tag, as in the following picture. Unfortunately, link **T1** created for an equation with manual tag points to the end of the equation and not to the actual tag.
The destinations of hyperlinks can be tested, e.g., by clicking the links in zoomed-in PDF viewer.

[image: Actual result]

How can anchors of such links pointing to custom tags be corrected to achieve results like in the image below?

[image: Desired result]

Answer (score 1):

Put the target inside the tag:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412381:
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\linkdest}[1]{\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{#1}{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
        1 + 1 &= 2 \text{.} \tag{\linkdest{htar:target1}{T1}} \\
        2 + 2 &= 4 \text{.} \label{eq:equation1}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\noindent eq.~\hyperlink{htar:target1}{T1}.

\noindent eq.~\ref{eq:equation1}.

\end{document}
```