# Beamer: hypertarget pointing with custom TOC

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, hypertarget

I'm trying to make a toc (named list of todos), list senteces, highlighted with custom command `\todo`, before series of frames created via allowframebreaks. Hope the MWE tell it better:

```
\makeatletter%%! TEX root = asd-beamer.tex
\let\@starttocorig\@starttoc
\makeatother%%

\documentclass[t,10pt,xcolor={usenames},fleqn]{beamer}

\usepackage{lipsum}
%% colors
\definecolor{todo}{rgb}{0.75, 0.0, 0.2}

%define \mycontentsline
\makeatletter
\protected\def\Hy@toclinkstart{\hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}}
\protected\def\Hy@toclinkend{\hyper@linkend}
\def\mycontentsline#1#2#3#4{%
    
  \begingroup
    \Hy@safe@activestrue
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \def\noexpand\Hy@tocdestname{#4}%
  }\x
  \ifx\Hy@tocdestname\ltx@empty
    \csname l@#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
  \else
    \ifcase\Hy@linktoc % none
      \csname l@#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
    \or % section
      \csname l@#1\endcsname{%
          \Hy@toclinkstart{#2}\Hy@toclinkend
      }{#3}%
    \or % page
      \def\Hy@temp{#3}%
      \ifx\Hy@temp\ltx@empty
        \csname l@#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
      \else
        \csname l@#1\endcsname{{#2}}{%
            \Hy@toclinkstart{#3}\Hy@toclinkend
        }%
      \fi
    \else % all
      \def\Hy@temp{#3}%
      \ifx\Hy@temp\ltx@empty
        \csname l@#1\endcsname{%
            \Hy@toclinkstart{#2}\Hy@toclinkend
        }{}%
      \else
        \csname l@#1\endcsname{%
            \Hy@toclinkstart{#2}\Hy@toclinkend
        }{%
            \Hy@toclinkstart{#3}\Hy@toclinkend
        }%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  }

\makeatother
%%%
\makeatletter%%see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411987/how-to-fix-hypertargets-directing-links-to-the-line-after-the-target-it-looks-l
%\newcommand{\linkdest}[2][][]{\phantomsection\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{#1}{#2}}\label{sec:#1}}
\newcommand{\linkdest}[2][\@empty]{%
    \hypertarget{\@empty}{#1}
\Hy@raisedlink{%1
\hypertarget{#2}{}
}%1
%\phantomsection\label{#2}
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{todokey}%conta i todo totali per auto ref
\newcounter{todosectionlist}% conta i todo prima di keywordlist

\newcommand\todo[2][todo-\thetodokey]{%todo
    \addtocounter{todokey}{1}
    \noindent{%
    \phantomsection% comment out if hyperref is not used
    \linkdest[\protect\color{todo}{#2}]{#1}%
    }%
    \addtocontents{todo-\thetodosectionlist}{\protect\mycontentsline{subsection}{\parbox{0.4\textwidth}{#2}}{}{#1}}
%\addcontentsline{todo-\protect\thetodosectionlist}{subsubsection}{\textbullet\protect\hyperlink{#1}{#2}\protect\hspace{1mm}}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listoftodosbasic}{%listoftodos
    \@starttocorig{todo-\thetodosectionlist}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\listtodosname{TODO}%listoftodo
\newcommand\listoftodos{%
    \addtocounter{todosectionlist}{1}
    \listtodosname\phantomsection: \listoftodosbasic}

% Let's get started
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,fragile]{TOC}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\part{A part}%\linkdest{intro}%
\section{Things to do}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,fragile]{List of todos}\linkdest{rl20todo}
\listoftodos
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,fragile]{Lista di todos}
\begin{itemize}
    \item\lipsum[1-2]%
    \item monday: \todo{monday-todo}%
        \lipsum[1-4]%
    \item tuesday: \todo{tuesday-todo}%
        \lipsum[1-3]%
    \item wednesday: \todo{wednesday-todo}%
        \lipsum[1-3]%
    \item thursday: \todo{thursday-todo}%
        \lipsum[1-3]%
    \item friday: \todo{friday-todo}%
        \lipsum[1-3]%
    \item saturday: \todo{saturday-todo}%
        \lipsum[1-3]%
    \item sunday: \todo{sunday-todo}%
        \lipsum[1-3]%

\end{itemize}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Also need to define `\mycontentsline` to get rid of some strange problem (I thought to remove macro `\mycontentsline` to use `\mycontentsline`, since seems to NOT related to this problem, but then the links doesn't work).

My problems are:

1. Links of todo's TOC point one line below: see [How to fix hypertargets directing links to the line after the target? It looks like a bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411987/how-to-fix-hypertargets-directing-links-to-the-line-after-the-target-it-looks-l).
   The solution I found is to use twice hypertarget inside `\linkdest` as if I use only one hypertarget the target is displaced in its position in the page.
2. Optional: I would like to see if todo's TOC looks better on two columns but seems difficult to me.

Hope not too messy to look into.

Best regards.

Comment: Well I can't look during the next week but your contentsline definition looks unneeded.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: you are right I've tested now, it compile with contentsline. I've redefined as mycontentsline since in my full code can't get rid of a "missing }" warning, but prabably was not related to this part of the code.

Comment: I tested the MWE with \contentsline instead of \mycontentsline but links don't work, so I just make it clear in the post.